# Calculating with a hidden number

Tags: c#, calculated-field

Design:

```
ComboBox1__txtBox1__txtBox2___txtBox3
```

When you select a name in comboBox1 a number is called with DataBinding in txtBox1 and txtBox2.

```
double a1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
double b1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

textBox3.Text = (a1 * b1).ToString();
```

How can I make this so that the textBox2 wouldn't be seen in the design. If I set textBox2 Properties Visible to false I get an error.

Comment: You should tell us what the error is.

Comment: If i hide the txtBox2 I get Input string was not in a correct format.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this.

```
<asp:HiddenField id="InvisibleField" runat="server" />
```

Assign the result of (a1 * b1).ToString(); to "InvisibleField".

Comment: Like this?


`double a1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
double b1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);

textBox3.Text = (a1 * b1).ToString();
textBox3.Text = "InvisibleField";
<asp:HiddenField id="InvisibleField" runat="server" />`